# nginx + php-fpm not writing php access log although there is configuration option

Tags: nginx, logging, php-fpm

I am looking at an nginx server with php-fpm. I see the access.log directive inside the pool configuration /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
; The access log file
; Default: not set
access.log = /var/log/$pool.php.access.log
```

However the access log file /var/log/www.php.access.log was not created. I created this file manually but still it was not being populated.

The PHP manual does not list an access.log configuration

http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

This post says that there is no access log for fastcgit

[Is there an access log for fastcgi?](https://serverfault.com/questions/375432/is-there-an-access-log-for-fastcgi)

So not sure whether the access.log configuration is even valid. What I would like to see is logging of all requests that pass through from nginx to the php application.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please post the full server config.

Comment: Here is the php-fpm.conf

`[global]
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf`

Here is the www.conf inside pool.d

`[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 500
pm.start_servers = 25
pm.min_spare_servers = 25
pm.max_spare_servers = 50
chdir = /`

Comment: BTW I had commented the access.log statement out because it was not working.

Comment: Have you tried to create that file manually with correct permissions?

Comment: Yes, I did create the file with correct permissions. I even tried 666 for the permissions. But that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you reload php-fpm? It's OK in my mac.

```
/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
access.log = /var/log/www.log
```

Reload php-fpm

```
kill -USR2 2233
```

2233 is php-fpm process id

Comment: Thanks for posting your response. This happened long time back. So not sure how it was handled after that.

Answer (score -2):

Move your logging to Nginx as PHP-FPM does not have an access log. For more details about PHP-FPM's configuration options [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php).

To apply the logging by Nginx you can also use variables but there are constraints to this you may not want to deal with. For details [see here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html).

Nginx config with access log only on PHP level without using variables:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    listen          [::]:80;
    server_name     www.mysite.com;

    root            /var/www/www.mysite.com;
    access_log      off;

    location / {
            ...
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            access_log              /var/log/www.log;
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "PHP-FPM does not have an access log. For more details...", but the link you give is to a page that *does* document FPM's "access.log" directive. (Maybe you were looking for global directives? It's per-pool.)

Comment: @DominicScheirlinck I think it [didn't have at the time](https://web.archive.org/web/20161120055438/https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php)